# How to get system time in Zephyr RTOS?

Tags: systemtime, zephyr-rtos

I'm looking for ways to get current system time displayed in Zephyr RTOS(2.0) from user-space area.
I'm using **gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu** tool-chain.
Something similar to **'localtime**' supported in GCC.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing on Zephyr because this is an OS for embedded hardware and does not have the features of a full fledged OS. The C library function localtime gets its information from the OS as can be described in the links below:-

- [C Date Time Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/articles/cdatetime/)
- [The GNU C Library Broken Down Time](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Broken_002ddown-Time.html)
- [Localtime Linux Man Page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime)

This is something that Zephyr does not have because most embedded hardware have no access to the internet and therefore have no concept of real time. The closest thing you can find on Zephyr are Kernel clocks and kernel timing services. Please see links below for more information:-

- [Kernel Clocks](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/1.9.0/kernel/timing/clocks.html)
- [Kernel Timing](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/reference/kernel/timing/clocks.html)